# Why is the Iphone 5s screen width in chrome wider than my 6s when held up to my monitor?

Tags: css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

Hey Guy's I'm doing the media queries for my website right now. I'm currently doing mobile and I'm using chrome's different presets in the devtools to start out. I know you shouldn't design around devices but I wanted to see what my website would look like on the 5s and the screen width is huuge. Way bigger than my 6s when held up against the screen? I do have a 25inch monitor. Is this the reason I really need my design to look proportinate on all devices. It would suck to realize I spent all that time designing a proportionate mobile display for an ipad mini

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

header {
 background-image: url(../img/contact.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
}

.contact-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-weight: bolder;
 margin: 0;
}

/*---NAV---*/

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

 nav ul {
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---MAIN---*/

.contact h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.contact h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.quote-info {
 width: 27%;
 margin: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.2);
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.quote-info form {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.quote-info input, .quote-info textarea {
 width: 85%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding: 3px;
}

.quote-info p {
 color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.45rem;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.quote-info .send-quote {
 width: 87%;
 background-color: red;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 padding: 5px;
}

.send-quote:hover {
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
 background-color: #cc0000;
}

textarea {
 resize: none;
}

hr {
 width: 100%;
 color: rgba(102, 102, 102);
}

.contact .container {
 display: flex;
}

.contact-info {
 width: 73%;
}

.contact-info h3 {
 color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 margin-left: 25px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contact-info h3:after {
 content: '';
 height: 1.5px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top: -35px;
}

.contact-numbers div {
 margin-left: 30px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.35rem;
}

.contact-numbers i {
 color: red;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 29%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.social .inner {
 width: 100%;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 29%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}


.footer h1 span {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -17px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 padding: 0;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 99.5%;
}

.footer button {
 float: right;
 margin-top: -17px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*------MEDIA-QUERIES------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1124px) {

 .quote-info {
  width: 30%;
 }   

 .quote-info input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .quote-info textarea {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .contact h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info {
  margin-left: -10px; 
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.4rem;: 
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;: 
 }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
 .quote-info input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .contact h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info {
  margin-left: -10px; 
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;: 
 }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {

 .quote-info {
  width: 25%;
 }

 .quote-info input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .contact h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info {
  margin-left: -10px; 
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.5rem;: 
 }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
 .quote-info {
  width: 25%;
 }

 .quote-info input, .quote-info textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  margin-top: 7px;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1700px) {
 .quote-info {
  width: 25%;
 }

 .quote-info input, .quote-info textarea, {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1800px) {
 .quote-info {
  width: 23%;
 }

 .quote-info input, .quote-info textarea, {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1900px) {
 .quote-info {
  width: 25%;
 }

 .quote-info input, .quote-info textarea, {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 .quote-info {
  width: 30%;
 }   

 .quote-info input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .quote-info textarea {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .contact h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info {
  margin-left: -20px; 
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.4rem;: 
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;: 
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 924px) {

 .logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 .quote-info {
  width: 35%;
 }   

 .quote-info input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .quote-info textarea {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .contact h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info {
  margin-left: -20px; 
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.4rem;: 
 }

 .contact-info p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;: 
 }

 .links a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 824px) {

    .footer .contact p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 3px;
 }

 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
 }

 .contact-info h3 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 95%;
  top: -25px;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 .contact-numbers p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
 }

 .quote-info {
  width: 35%;
 }

 .quote-info textarea {
  font-size: 1rem;
 }

 .quote-info input{
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 8.5%;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 20px;
 }

}

/*---TABLET---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .contact h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .contact h2:before {
  width: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
 }

 .contact h2:after {
  width: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
 }

 header, .contact-wrapper {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .quote-info {
  width: 40%;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info h3 {
  margin-left: 20px;
 }

 .contact-numbers div {
  margin-left: 20px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 731px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 6%;
 }

 .contact .inner p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

 .footer .contact p {
  margin: 3px;
 }

}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE-MOBILE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {
 
 /*---NAV---*/

 nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .contact-info {
  margin-left: -12px;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
 }

 .quote-info p {
  top: 0;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 667px) and (max-height: 375px) {
 header {
  background-position: 0px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 626px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
 }

 .quote-info {
  width: 85%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
 }

 .quote-info input, 
 .quote-info textarea {
  width: 85.5%;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
 }

 .quote-info .send-quote {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 .quote-info p {
  top: 0;
 }

 .contact .container {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .contact-info {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .contact-info i {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 100%;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-right:5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 98%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 .quote-info {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }

 .quote-info p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  top: 0;
 }

 .quote-info input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
 }

 .contact h3:after {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .contact .container {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .social .inner:before {
  width: 100vw;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -5px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
 nav li {
  font-size: 1.27rem;
  margin-right: 7px;
 }

 .after:after {
  left: 5.5px;
  top: 4px;
 }

 .logo {
  margin-left: 15px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 517px) {

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3.3rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
     content: '';
     height: 2px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
  left: 0;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -5px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

/*---MOBILE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .m1, .m2, .m3 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  transition:all .3s ease;
  opacity:1;
 }

 .hamburger-open .m1{transform: rotate(45deg) translate(4px, 12px);}
 .hamburger-open .m2{opacity:0}
 .hamburger-open .m3{transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(3px, -12px);}

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
 }

 .quote-info {
  width: 90%;
 }

 .quote-info p {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
 }

 .contact .container {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .contact-info h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 37px;
 }

 .contact-info h3:after {
  width: 143%;
 }

 .contact-numbers {
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: 17px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: 5px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 97%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {

 .contact-info i, .contact-info p {
  margin-left: 12px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Contact | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="contact-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1" id="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2" id="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3" id="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="contact" id="quote">
  <h2>Get in touch</h2>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="quote-info">
    <form action="">
     <p>Get a Quote</p>

     <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email">

     <textarea name="project-details" id="" cols="40" rows="7" placeholder="Give us the specifics on your project"></textarea>

     <button class="send-quote">Send</button>
    </form>
   </div>

   <div class="contact-info">
    <h3>Contact info</h3>

    <div class="contact-numbers">
     <div>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(208)546-7827 -Matt</p>
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <p>(208)546-7827 -Keegan</p>
     </div>

     <div>
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <p>P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
      <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
      <p>KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <hr>
 
 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Quick Links</span></h1>

     <a href="index.html">Home</a>
     <a href="about.html">About</a>
     <a href="about.html#services">Services</a>
     <a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
     <a href="contact.html#quote">Quote</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Social</span></h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send us some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1><span>Contact</span></h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
 <script src="../script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: could be something to do with the `<meta>` tags. Can you show us your code and screenshot of "huuge" screen width?

Comment: Two possibilities. The first is an iPhone has a higher DPI (dots per inch) than your desktop monitor. The second is that Chrome might have automatically zoomed out some to fit the simulated screen within the current viewport. (And it might well be both.)

Comment: My meta looks good

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`